# Is There way to take the contents of an array and store it into a pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am writing a a program that produces similar results to the command ls -l. Currently I can produce the results through loops, but now I want to store certain variables into a linked list so I can later put it through a lexical-graphic sorter. I can store most of the variable into the node properly, but the problems stems from when I'm trying to store the permission variable. Is there a way I can get the contents of an char[] to a char *?

With the way I have it set up the permissions are stored in a char[], but I haven't found away to use char[] as a return type, so I decided a char * would be more appropriate but now I'm trying to figure out how to go from char[] to a char*.

```
char* find_perms(mode_t st) {
    char* perms_ptr;
    char perms[11];
    if(st && S_ISREG(st)) perms[0]='-';
    else if(st && S_ISDIR(st)) perms[0]='d';
    else if(st && S_ISFIFO(st)) perms[0]='|';
    else if(st && S_ISSOCK(st)) perms[0]='s';
    else if(st && S_ISCHR(st)) perms[0]='c';
    else if(st && S_ISBLK(st)) perms[0]='b';
    else perms[0]='l';  // S_ISLNK
    perms[1] = (st && S_IRUSR) ? 'r':'-';
    perms[2] = (st && S_IWUSR) ? 'w':'-';
    perms[3] = (st && S_IXUSR) ? 'x':'-';
    perms[4] = (st && S_IRGRP) ? 'r':'-';
    perms[5] = (st && S_IWGRP) ? 'w':'-';
    perms[6] = (st && S_IXGRP) ? 'x':'-';
    perms[7] = (st && S_IROTH) ? 'r':'-';
    perms[8] = (st && S_IWOTH) ? 'w':'-';
    perms[9] = (st && S_IXOTH) ? 'x':'-';
    perms[10] = '\0';
    printf("%s ",perms);
    perms_ptr = perms;
    return perms_ptr;
}
```

as it is right now this does return a char*, but instead of pointing to the array that I was hoping I could use later it points to an empty string. When I used gdb to view what perms_ptr was pointing to it just showed up as "".

Comment: Pointers cannot store a data rather than an address, instead they can just point.

Comment: make your `perms` a `static` char array.

Comment: @Revolver Please don't recommend that, it will cause other problems unless they're careful.

Comment: Have a look at `strdup`.

Comment: One needs to use precise language. You don't store the contents of an array in a pointer, ever. You make a pointer **point at** an array. That's what pointers do. They point at things. They store **addresses** of things, not their contents.

Answer (score 1):

A char [] symbol can be accessed exactly like a char *. It can be easily returned, but it has to be dynamically allocated inside the function or otherwise passed as a parameter of the function.

Returning a local variable is a mistake that leads to undefined behaviour, because it is stored in the stack and will be overwritten as soon as the funtion returns.

In your function returning `perms` is ok (no need to define another pointer) if you allocate it with
`perms = malloc (11);`

(You will have to free it outside your function).

Comment: The dynamic allocation is likely the best here as it allows for any number of file permission to be handled and collected in a list..

Comment: A `char []` is not a `char *`. The fact it is automatically converted in many contexts does not make it one. Do not teach people this wrong information.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I edited the answer in order to clarify the *pratical* meaning of my sentence. Check if it's better.